# Cant use spring-boot-starter-web dependecies when running tests

Tags: java, spring, gradle, dependencies, spring-boot

I have multi-module project using gradle(web,common,batch)

The project is running fine

however when I am trying to run junit from test folder of batch module when the spring comes up I get this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/http/converter/xml/MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter
```

I checked dependency tree from the batch module:

```
<batch>gradle -q dependencies --configuration testRuntime
```

And I see in the buttom FAILED while trying to import spring-boot-start-web

```
.....
|    |         +--- com.caucho:resin-hessian:4.0.23
|    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:3.1.0.RELEASE -> 4.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |         +--- com.adobe.blazeds:blazeds-common:3.2.0.3978
|    |         +--- com.adobe.blazeds:blazeds-proxy:3.2.0.3978
|    |         +--- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.2
|    |         +--- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.2 (*)
|    |         \--- org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5
|    +--- com.mycompany.services.configuration:ConfigurationManager:2.0.8 (*)
|    +--- com.caucho:resin-hessian:4.0.23
|    +--- mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.34
|    \--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:1.2.1.RELEASE
|    +--- junit:junit:4.12
|    |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
|    +--- org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.8
|    |    +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1 -> 1.3
|    |    \--- org.objenesis:objenesis:2.1
|    +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
|    +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3
|    |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-test:4.1.4.RELEASE
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.4.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-test:3.0.2.RELEASE
|    +--- junit:junit:4.11 -> 4.12 (*)
|    +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3
|    \--- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-core:3.0.2.RELEASE (*)
\--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web: FAILED
```

this is my build.gradle on the batch module:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-release" }
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:$project.ext.springBootVersion")

    }
}

description = 'batch'

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch:$project.ext.springBootVersion")
    testRuntime("org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-test:$project.ext.springBatchVersion") {
        exclude(module: 'spring-test')
        exclude(module: 'spring-jdbc')
        exclude(module: 'commons-io')
        exclude(module: 'commons-collections')
    }

    /* compile ('org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:4.1.2.RELEASE')*/
    compile project(":common")
    testRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")

}
```

Any idea what's wrong ?

Thank you.

Comment: It's required at runtime or at compile time?

Comment: runtime. in compile time I got no problems but when I run  my test and the spring container comes up I get this exception. after digging I saw that method comes inside the spring-boot-starer-web dependecy.

Comment: Is the project available online?

Comment: A bit problematic but if I have no choice ill work for it. please tell me if any more details needed for you to understand this way the prob? ..

Comment: I guess that is the best option to solve the problem :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to provide a version number when you're declaring the dependency or you need to apply the Spring Boot plugin (you've declared the plugin as a build script dependency, but don't appear to have applied it).

When the Spring Boot plugin is applied it'll automatically set the version of spring-boot-starter-web to the same version as the plugin. You can see a [list of all the versions](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-dependency-versions) that the plugin can set for you in the documentation.

Comment: I provided the version as you suggested. still same error.     compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:$project.ext.springBootVersion")

Comment: What does `gradle --dependencies` say now? Previously it said `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web: FAILED` (note the missing version number). If you've provided the version number, it should now be something like `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.2.1.RELEASE`

Comment: You nailed it man!! Pleaes explain me why I needed the apply spring-plugin for that to work ?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of options, change:

`testRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")`

to:

`compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")`

Also, my Spring Boot `build.gradle` file does not use the `:$project.ext.springBatchVersion` variable. It seems to set the variables just fine - for example, here is my (condensed) example `build.gradle` file.:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.1.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.2.1'
}
```

Comment: When i added actuator dependency as testRuntime I got failed when running again dependencies tree with gradle :+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web: FAILED
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator: FAILED

Comment: I guess my next step would be to look for the project online, like @Opal. If you could strip it down to the bare minimum that produces the error, it would be helpful. If it turns out others can build it, it might be a configuration issue.